# What will be the effect of adding a 10k load resistor to this circuit?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, current, circuit-design, zener

[image: Circuit]

### Background

When ignoring the 10k Resistor:

- When Vsupply = 28V, I have worked out that the current through ZD1 = 4.95mA.
- When Vsupply = 14V, I have worked out that the current through ZD1 = 4.9mA.

### Question

```
     When the 10k resistor is included:
     How will things change if the current in R4 which is a 10k resistor is included.

     I am trying to figure out the current variations in ZD1. Therefore, i want to know if:

     1 : There will be no current variations through ZD1.

     2 : The current variations through ZD1 will be bigger.

     3 : The current variations through ZD1 will be smaller.
```

### My Answer

I think that the current variations will be smaller cause the 10k resistor will take away some of the stress that the diode ZD1 is taking. Please let me know if this is correct and if it isn't please help me understand why, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuit attempts to deliver 5 mA of current into whatever is connected between the collector and ground (presumed to be the lower node in the circuit). This current will vary a bit with a changing power rail (Vsupply) but I have assumed 5 mA.

ZD2 (a 5.6 volt zener) ensures that there will be about 5 volts across the emitter resistor R1 (1 kohm). This means that with a fairly decent accuracy, the current into ZD1 (the collector current) will be about 5 mA. Given that ZD1 is a 5.6 volt zener and that a 10 k resistor is then placed across it, the current into the 10 k resistor will be 0.56 mA. So, now the ZD1 current will be 5 mA - 0.56 mA = 4.44 mA.

Comment: So does that mean that the answer is 1)There will be no current variations through ZD1. when including the 10k resistor?

Comment: "Given that ZD1 is a 5.6 volt zener and that a 10 k resistor is then placed across it, the current into the 10 k resistor will be 0.56 mA. So, now the ZD1 current will be 5 mA - 0.56 mA = 4.44 mA."

Comment: That's the sort of advice I respect,

Comment: @John the zener (ZD1) current will drop from 5 mA to 4.44 mA.

Comment: ... although it was clear these were typos...

Comment: Yes thank you. I understand that putting a 10k resistor in will obviously reduce the current through ZD1 but the question is about the variation in current. When using a 28V supply, the current through ZD1 is 4.95mA without the 10k and 4.39mA with it, therefore there is a difference of 0.56mA. When using a 14V supply, the current through ZD1 is 4.9mA without the 10k and 4.34mA with it, therefore there is a difference of 0.56mA. I both cases the difference is 0.56mA so does this not mean that there will be no current varaition through ZD1?

Comment: Your numbers (and my answer) tell you that the zener current does vary so I'm not sure which bit you are stuck with. Maybe I don't understand what scenario you are considering?

Comment: I think i'm a bit confused by the question we were given. The question says "How will things change if we include the current in R4 which is a 10k resistor" and then the options are numbers 1-3 in the question i have given.  I'm not sure if it means will the current in ZD1 decease with the 10k or comparing the 28V/14V supply will the variations in current in ZD1 stay the same.

Comment: Well, you are armed with all the potential answers and information, all you have to do is figure out what the question means. I can't figure out what the question means if you don't understand it. I can only answer questions that you raise and that was clear enough but if you think that might be wrong, you have to do some digging.

Comment: Ok thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

The voltage across ZD2 will be 5.6 V. Since the voltage between base and emitter is approximately 0.6 V, the voltage across R1 will be 5 V. According to Ohm's law, this will give a current of 5 mA. Therefore the emitter current and the collector current are both 5 mA (assuming a high current gain beta)). Without the 10 kOhm resistor, this will also be the current that flows through ZD1.

Adding the 10 kOhm resistor will hardly change the collector current. However, since the voltage across ZD1 is 5.6 V, a current of 0.56 mA will flow through the 10 kohm resistor. Thus, the current through ZD1 will change to about 4.44 mA. This small change in current will hardly change the voltage across ZD2.